# VB.NET WCF Detach Debugger

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, wcf, debugging, service

I'm trying to debug a WCF I compiled.

Problem is, I attached the debugger to the service from the wrong project.

I need some way to 'Detach the debugger' from a self-hosted windows service.

There only seems to be documentation on how to attach the debugger to a process, but nothing on how to DETACH one.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Debug menu and select the "Detach All" menu item.